# Javascript: queue multiple loading bars on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, queue

I am working on trying to queue multiple loading bars on multiple clicks and following a simple queue mechanism, but I am running into a simple issue of scoping where I can't access the queue variable to run all the functions I have stored after the onClick event has fired -

JS

```
var progressBar = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar');
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('start');
var funqueue = [];


var loadingBar = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
  progressBar[0].style.width = "10%";
  setTimeout(function() {
    progressBar[0].style.width = "30%";
    setTimeout(function() {
      progressBar[0].style.width = "50%";
      setTimeout(function() {
        progressBar[0].style.width = "100%";
        }, 2000)
      }, 500)
    }, 2000)    
  }, 1000); 
} 

button[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(funqueue);
    funqueue.push(loadingBar);
});

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(funqueue);    
  (funqueue.shift())();
}, 1000);
```

HTML

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  <button class="start">Start</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.progress-bar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

I have a few console logs here and there because I was trying to debug why the variable `funqueue` is not available across the scope. I am trying to achieve the behavior where my button if clicked three times, will run the `loadingIndicator` function three times.

Comment: Were are you loosing scope, and what function's you talking about?

Comment: I have mentioned above in the problem that `funqueue` does not exist in the last setTimeout function. And the loadingIndicator function is what I am inserting everytime there is a click event.

Comment: You executing a function before it's even been created. try doing ->  if (funqueue.length)
      (funqueue.shift())();

Comment: Also if you don't press the start button within 1 second, it's not going to do anything,.. Did you mean to use setInterval instead.

Comment: Thanks, that works! @Keith